# Could not able to connect with database

Tags: php, xampp

Why I could not able to connect with database ? I have one file 'connect.inc.php' Which have following code:

```
     <?php
        $conn_error='Could not connect.';
        $mysql_host='localhost';
        $mysql_user='root';
        $mysql_pass='';
        $mysql_db='a_database';
        if(!@mysqli_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$mysql_db)
         || !@mysqli_select_db(mysqli_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user
         ,$mysql_pass,$mysql_db), $mysql_db))
         {
         die($conn_error);
         }
        ?>
```

And another is index page Which have following code:

```
        <?php
        require 'connect.inc.php';
        echo 'Ok';
        ?>
```

And this is the error:

```
         Warning: require(connect.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such
         file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\ConnectingToServerAndDatabase
         \index.php on line 2


        Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'connect.inc
        php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\
        ConnectingToServerAndDatabase\index.php on line 2
```

[image: Screen Shot of error.]

Comment: @Option The OP does use `mysqli`...

Comment: The issue is the inclusion of that php file, not the connection to the database.

Comment: I had use mysqli_ only.

Comment: as per your code your connect.inc.php file should be in same dir where index file located, confirm that

Comment: The connection code itself makes no sense at all: first remove those `@` characters, second you need to store the connection object you receive back from `mysqli_connect()`, otherwise you won't be able to use the connection afterwards and third one connection attempt is enough, no need to repeat it.

Comment: both are in same directory

Comment: Can you please check your file name is exactly like " connect.inc.php " ?

Comment: @Option You are in very good company. This question is a very typical example of people commenting and answering faster than they can actually read the question, more concerned with contributing _anything_ instead of at least taking the time to understand the question. Very sad.

Answer (score 0):

> Warning: require(connect.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such
>            file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\ConnectingToServerAndDatabase
>            \index.php on line 2
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'connect.inc
>     php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\
>     ConnectingToServerAndDatabase\index.php on line 2

Your `connect.inc.php` file should be in same directory where `index.php` exists

You may use below command to set include path

```
set_include_path(get_include_path().":"."/path/to/your/conn_file_directory"); 

# and then use 
require 'connect.inc.php'
```

OR use `require __DIR__ . "/relative/path/from/current/file"`

**mysql_** functions are  now deprecated, so use **mysqli_** functions.

Comment: I had used mysqli_ only.